# Merge mysql rows with same id using 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, merge, rows

I have a mysql database with 2 tables: songideen, kommentare. In "songideen" you can store songs, in "kommentare" you can comment them. Both tables are linked via LEFT JOIN.
How to merge the rows (in case a song has 2 or more comments) so all comments are seperated by ',' within one row? In this example I want to combine the second and the third row:

```
Name   Arbeitstitel    Datum      mp3    ID  Kommentare    KommentarID
Lukas   Titeltest    2016-06-06  Link     1   comment      1 
Jannik  Titeltest2   2016-07-06  Link2    2   comment2     2
Jannik  Titeltest2   2016-07-06  Link2    2   comment3     2
Andi    Titeltest3   2016-07-20  Link3    3   comment4     3
```

I alrady tried it this way, but it doesn't work:

```
 $sql = "SELECT songideen.Name, songideen.Arbeitstitel, songideen.Datum, songideen.mp3, songideen.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(kommentare.Kommentar SEPARATOR ',') AS KommentarIDs, kommentare.KommentarID
                FROM songideen
                LEFT JOIN kommentare
                ON songideen.ID=kommentare.KommentarID
                GROUP BY kommentare.KommentarID";
```

Comment: please post what ever that's in the image as text in the question

Comment: Done, hope this is ok so

Comment: Can you show the structure of the tables?

Answer (score 1):

You needed to group by `songideen.ID`. Since there are records in the `songideen` table without any comment in `kommentare` table.

```
SELECT
    songideen.Name,
    songideen.Arbeitstitel,
    songideen.Datum,
    songideen.mp3,
    songideen.ID,
    GROUP_CONCAT(kommentare.Kommentar SEPARATOR ',') AS KommentarIDs,
    kommentare.KommentarID
FROM songideen
LEFT JOIN kommentare ON songideen.ID = kommentare.KommentarID
GROUP BY songideen.ID ;
```

**Note:**

In your case you were grouping the result set by `kommentare.kommentarID`. For records in `songideen` table which don't have any comment in the `kommentare` table will result in `NULL` value of `kommentare.kommentarID`. Thus your final result set will consist of those records which have corresponding comments in the `kommentare` table plus one entry for all the `NULL` entries found in `kommentare` table.

Answer (score 0):

use following queries for your output.

```
$sql = "SELECT s.Name, s.Arbeitstitel, s.Datum, s.mp3, s.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(k.Kommentar SEPARATOR ',') AS KommentarIDs, k.KommentarID,(SELECT count(*) FROM  kommentare  where KommentarID= s.ID) as commentCount
                FROM songideen s , kommentare k
                where s.ID=k.KommentarID            
                GROUP BY k.KommentarID
                    having commentCount>2
                ";
```

explanation:

here we are using inner join you will not get any duplicates. and using having you can restrict number comments

Comment: The problem here is that only songs WITH comments are shown. But there exist songs without a comment (and therefore without KommentarID).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM songideen
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT (kommentare SEPARATOR ','), KommentarID
FROM kommentare
GROUP BY KommentarID) AS kommentare
  ON kommentare.KommentarID = songideen.id
```

`LEFT JOIN` on a subquery which returns the concatenated `kommentare` grouped by the `KommentarID`.

But tbh, you should rework your table design, or at least change some names of columns.

`kommentare`.`KommentarID` - This doesn't seem to be the actual identifier for `kommentare`, but is the id of the corresponding `songideen`.`id`, so this should be called `songideenID` so you can easily see, this is the column which builds the relation between the tables.

Missing "actual" KommentarID - what is the `primary key` in your `kommentare` table? An `auto_increment` `int` `primary key` would feel very intuitively.

It would then look loke this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/150e7/4

```
SELECT
  *
FROM songideen 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(Kommentare SEPARATOR ',') AS kommentar, songideenID
FROM kommentare 
GROUP BY songideenID) AS kommentare USING(songideenID)
```

Comment: I nearly copied the Schema to phpmyadmin and the SQL to my php file, still doesn't work :/

Comment: nearly? :p Well just take your time in debugging it - if you want to change the structure. You can do the steps one by one if needed as I only added one column to `kommentare` and renamed the songideenID in both tables. Though what does "doesn't work" mean? wrong result?

Comment: Yeah, I just need some time for the debugging. But thanks for your help! :-)  Another tiny question: what's the best way to add another row "User" in the table "kommentare" to show who has written this comment? I probably also need GROUP_CONCAT for this, right?

Comment: Depends on what data you have. If `user` is an own entity in your database (there is a `user` table) you take the userId into `kommentare`. If you have an online form with an input field, where I could write some random name when commenting, it is good enough to just write the name into the field.

Comment: For both cases the queries would look a little different, if it is "just" a name, without database-entity behind it, you could just add the `group_concat` into the subquery. If there is a `user` table involved you join on it inside the subquery and then `group_concat` on the name field.

Comment: can please you accept / upvote the answer (1000111's too), so others know your problem is solved